# .net core API controller does not process identity authentication and authorization

Tags: controller, asp.net-core-mvc, identity

I have a .NETcore MVC project contains controller and API controllers in the same site, which uses basic identity authentication / authorization.  The API controllers is designed for local view or potential for other application.  I would expect Javascript in local view could call API by passing in the authentication info (which can be seen in the header: aspNetCore.Identity.Application).  However, it never reached API and returned 401 error.
The same design worked in ASP.NET but broke in ASP.net core.

The following are the attributes of the controller.  If I set it to [AllowAnonymous], the User info is not set at all.

[Route("api/[controller]")]

[ApiController]

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]

[Authorize(Roles = "Admin,User")]
```

Comment: Have you got JwtToken in your js?

Comment: No.  The js in MVC view trying to call an API controller in the same site.  I would expect the call  carries identity authentication to the API controller, which worked in .NET but .NET core.  JWT authorization is reserved for calls from another site.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do this. In the controller, `AuthenticationSchemes` can be assigned to multiple authentication schemas.